# XeTex on ubuntu

Tags: xetex

I got an error

```
 (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/base/themes/o/beamerouterthemedefault.st
 y))) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
 ! 
 ********************************************
 * XeTeX is required to compile this document.
 * Sorry!
 ********************************************.
 \RequireXeTeX ...********************************}
                                              \endgroup \fi 
 l.18 \RequireXeTeX
```

But in the command line I can call `xelatex` and `xetex`.
It looks like the problem is with `lexlive`, but I have installed it.
What can be the problem?

Comment: Are you starting the TeX processor out of an editor? Normally those use `latex` or `pdftex` as default engines, you need to change it to `xelatex` or `xetex` in the editor. If you are using TeX Works coming with TeX Live, there is a dropdown menu next to the "compile button". It is no problem with TeX Live, as it is working on the command line, your editor is just using the wrong engine by default for this file.

Comment: to compile I use `lualatex`, do you know how can I set it up?

Comment: Could you please post a full example of your code? It looks like it is an `fontspec` error, but `fontspec` should work with `lualatex`…

Comment: We need more detail of what is actually being done: you don't get this error 'by accident'.